# Offline sync and version control program dropbox-alike recommendation? (commercial or free, W10 compatible)

Tags: windows, dropbox

Can you please recommend a program that can do realtime folder synchronization between 2 drives/folders on my PC in the background similar to how Dropbox or Onedrive is implemented, and ideally also provide a set time or number of copies of recoverable history for deleted or updated files (simple form of "version control").

Dropbox for example does all this but the destination is the cloud; i want it to be offline. Integration with windows explorer to provide folder checkmarks is also preferred but not required.

The reason i cannot run it as traditional backup is due to space limitations as backup programs like Macrium Reflect cannot update existing backups, therefore you need to remake a full backup each time (which takes long time) or provide incremental backups assuming that you have the available space.

Comment: Macrium Reflect is not a backup program, it's an imaging program. A backup program could easily cope with those requirements, maybe except the Windows Explorer integration. Some version control systems can also satisfy the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're not the only one who liked the idea of Briefcase; it was popular enough that there are replacements for it now that Microsoft has removed it from Windows. Consider [SyncFolder](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/syncfolder/9nc73mjwhsww#), and perhaps [ask](https://www.google.com/search?q=replacements+for+windows+briefcase) [the](https://www.bing.com/search?q=replacements+for+windows+briefcase) [bingleduck](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=replacements+for+windows+briefcase) about "Replacements for Windows Briefcase".